# How common are aprons made of bricks?

Tags: airport

I found this topic on an external site, it's about a Boeing 737-4 damaged during engine run up at Sialkot international Airport (Pakistan): [NL B734 Damaged During Engine Run Up](https://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=573541) ([photos](https://www.facebook.com/AME.World/posts/10152248845712798))

In the comments/discussion, people say that there is similar apron paving made of blocks at other major airports.

- Are there any photos or verification of lose-block apron?
- One comment says that London Heathrow has some, does somebody have any verification or Link?

  > Block paving is very common at airports. All over Heathrow and Gatwick. It works fine when its built correctly but if it's not maintained well then that happens.

Comment: http://www.sept.org/techpapers/330.pdf

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Hong Kong International Airport represents the largest single airfield installation of interlocking concrete pavements. Since most of the airport is on reclaimed land, anticipated settlement required that flexible asphalt pavement be used instead of rigid concrete for runways. Concrete pavers also provide a more fuel-resistant surface than asphalt.

[Source](http://www.paveshare.org/library/category/paver)

[image]

---

See also

- [Concrete Block Paving 
  for Airfields](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/33550/spec_35.pdf)
- [Airfield pavement design with concrete pavers](https://www.icpi.org/sites/default/files/techpapers/530.pdf)
- [Evolution of Interlocking Concrete Pavements for Airfields](http://ascelibrary.org/doi/abs/10.1061/40579%28271%2921)
- [THE USE OF INTERLOCKING CONCRETE BLOCKS ON AN AIRCRAFT PAVEMENT IN AUSTRALIA](http://www.sept.org/techpapers/54.pdf)

Comment: Can you provide any examples involving red gritty bricks?

Comment: That brick surface is so clean... if it wasn't for the giant plane there, I wouldn't believe it actually serviced planes!