# Which would be the best placement of an engine for a supersonic buisness jet that has an intake of 2-D ramp?

Tags: aircraft-design, supersonic, propulsion, engine-placement

I would also like to know if possible which would be the advantage/disadvantage of placing the engine under or over the wing for example.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Over the wing as in rear mounted on the fuselage, or over the actual wing? See: [Why not mount airliner jet engines above the wings?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/9680/14897)

Comment: Over the actual wing, sorry for not specifying.

Comment: Does the linked post answer the question, or are there supersonic-flight-specific issues you'd like addressed? Press **Edit** under your question to add all the relevant info so you can get specific and relevant answers.

Comment: The linked adressed helped, thank you very much!